# Convert MySQL BigInt(20) unix epoch time to datetime(3)

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix

```
select from_unixtime(floor(1510156036741/1000), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s');
```

'2017 8th November 07:47:16'

The above code outputs a timestamp which doesn't include millisecond precision. How would I convert an unix epoch time to a datetime(3) object which includes milliseconds?

It's possible to get microseconds like:

```
select from_unixtime(1510156036741/1000, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %f');
```

'2017 8th November 07:47:16 741000'

Is it possible to convert the microsecond result to milliseconds?

Comment: Since there isn't a format code for that, I'd just discard the last three characters of the microseconds. More complicated if you want to round, not truncate, of course.

Comment: I tried to discard the last three characters of the microsecond code by dividing by 1000 like: select from_unixtime(floor(1510156036741/1000), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s' '%f' / 1000);
The query didn't output anything though. How would I discard the last three characters?

Comment: With string operations, not numeric operations. i.e. `SUBSTR`. Moob's answer is another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit clunky, but you can extract the microsecond and divide it by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds. Here I've also cast it to an int and concatinated it with the formatted date to create the final date string:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  from_unixtime(1510156036741/1000, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s '),
  CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(1510156036741/1000))/1000 
  AS SIGNED)
);
```

> "2017 8th November 03:47:16 741"